# Auditing SSRS reports to get the last runtime and status on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have 3 tables in SQL Server storing data for every execution of SSRS report

- Subscription
- Catalog
- Users : default table for employees in the company

I want to get the following information :

- CreatedBy
- LastModifiedBy
- Path of the SSRS report
- Name of the SSRS report
- Last runtime
- Last status

Answer (score 0):

Your request is similar to something I have been working on a long time ago.

```
SELECT
        U1.UserName AS CreatedBy
       ,U2.UserName AS LastModifiedBy
       ,C.[path] AS [Path]
       ,C.[Name] AS [Name]
       ,S.LastRunTime
       ,S.LastStatus
       ,S.ExtensionSettings
    FROM [Subscriptions] AS S
    INNER JOIN [Catalog] AS C
        ON S.Report_OID = C.ItemID
    INNER JOIN [Users] AS U1 
        ON S.OwnerID = U1.UserID
    INNER JOIN [Users] AS U2 
        ON S.ModifiedByID = U2.UserID
 
    ORDER BY U1.UserName
    , U2.UserName
    , C.[path];
```